# Shemona Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Rashi, the waters of Noach started receding on the 1st of Sivan and the ground became "charava" on the 1st of Tishrei.  Since acc. to Rashi the months switch evenly from maleh to chaser, that 30+29+30+29= 118

Answer (score 4):

118 are the *dapim* in each of *Bava Kama* and *Bava M'tzia*.

Answer (score 4):

[Supposedly](http://www.aleppocodex.org/9.html), the number of pages missing in the Aleppo Codex from the beginning of the Torah until the first bit that we have is 118.

Answer (score 3):

Both Parshas Mishpatim and Parshas V'Eschanan have 118 Pesukim.

Answer (score 2):

118 different categories of tamei per Encyclopedia Talmudit, volume 19, columns 475–478.
http://www.dafyominotes.com/2012/10/basics-of-tumah-part-2-how-it-works.html?m=1